# how to calculate the time complexity of kurskal's algorithm which is may be O(E log E) = O(E log V).?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, time-complexity

Please tell me the procedure that how to calculate the time complexity of Kruskal's theorem? 
I know the algorithm of Kruskal algorithm but didn't know the pseudo code and calculation of time complexity ... the complexity of Kruskal algo is O(E log E) = O(E log V) (wikipedia). But I didn't know how to calculate that..

Answer (score 2):

Kruskal's algorithm is based on union-find of forests until they form a single tree. At each step you are connecting two trees by using a single edge.

The pseudo code (from [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kruskal%27s%5falgorithm#Pseudocode)):

```
tree = {}
for each v:
   make-set(v)
for each edge (u,v) ordered by w(u,v):
   if find(u) != find(v):
        tree.add((u,v))
        union(u,v)
return tree
```

The bottleneck of the algorithm is sorting the edges according to weight. Sorting is done in `O(nlogn)` at best, and we are sorting a list of size `E`, giving us total of `O(ElogE)=O(Elog(V^2))=O(2ElogV)=O(ElogV)`

Answer (score 0):

Kruskal algorithm in steps :-

```
1. Sort the edges by weight
2. Select from lowest to highest
3. Connect edge if they don't form the loop.
4. Repeat 2,3 until n-1 edges are connected.
```

**Time Complexity : -**

```
1. Sorting takes O(Elog(E))
2,3 : O(E) using efficient union-find .
```

**Overall :-** `O(Elog(E))`

**in a graph :-**

```
E = O(V^2)
logE = O(2*logV)
hence O(ElogE) = O(ElogV)
```